# How to calculate laplace function in python 3

Tags: python, statistics

i have this function

[image]

I can find table for it [in russian](https://100task.ru/sample/119.aspx), but i need to calculate it. I know I could calculate this without a separate function, but it would be nicer to do it with a single function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [scipy.special.erf](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.erf.html) which has similar signature
and apply some coefficients to have it matched your definition:

```
>>> from scipy.special import erf
>>> errf(1)
>>> Phi = lambda x: erf(x/2**0.5))/2
>>> Phi(1)
0.34134474606854293
```

EDIT:
The integral pant of `erf(z)` is: `integral(exp(-t**2), t=0..z)`
Your `Psi(z)` function on the other hand has: `integral(exp(-0.5*u**2), u=0..z)` in it
From that we can find `t = u / sqrt(2)`
When you change `dt` to `du` you get additional `1/sqrt(2)` factor
before the integral symbol and finally dividing by `2` gets you to your definition of `Psi`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works. But i do not understend how. Can you explain what happens after erf(? Why do you pass these values? For example, where the integration interval is specified